# why does lodash _.without() change the value of _?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am just trying out lodash in the node repl.

First I require lodash

```
_ = require('lodash')
```

Then I try one of the functions

```
_.without([1,2,3], 1)
[ 2, 3 ]
```

But if I run it again

```
> _.without([1,2,3], 1)
TypeError: Object 2,3 has no method 'without'
    at repl:1:4
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at emitKey (readline.js:1095:12)
```

Now _ (lodash lib) is an array?

Comment: _ is reserved by node to store value of last statement. So you have to use another variable name for lodash `var _dash = require('lodash');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in nodejs REPL _ is the result of the last expression. You should not use _ for anything in nodejs REPL.

http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html